"Неизвестно" или "не известно" в данном предложении?
Но нам не известна ни цель, ни мотивация его действий.

Выбираем слитное написание:
Но нам неизвестна ни цЕль, ни мотивация его дЕйствий.
Пояснение

В общем случае при отсутствии усилительных слов возможно как слитное, так и раздельное написание НЕ.

Сочетание ни цель, ни мотивация к усилительным словам не относится, сравнить: Никому не известна ни цель, ни мотивация его действий.

Интонационно больше подходит слитное написание, так как ударение переходит на однородные члены, а при раздельном написании НЕ логическим ударением обычно выделено слово с НЕ.


Примеры из Нацкорпуса
Даниил Ступа. Далекие годы (1970-1977) // «Ковчег», 2014.
Вот это и есть то, из-за чего неизвестна ни твоя судьба, ни Танина.
Аркадий Стругацкий, Борис Стругацкий. Обитаемый остров (1967-1969).
Ага! «…технология неизвестна ни в нашей стране, ни в других цивилизованных государствах (по довоенным данным)».
Дмитрий Губин. Гибридные режимы и спор на повышенных тонах (13.01.2017) // 2017.  Поэтому теория гибридных режимов не известна ни в изложении Стивена Левицки и Люкана Вэя, ни Беатрис Магалони, ни Джениффер Ганди, ни Ивана Крастева и Стивена Холмса, ни Дэвида Трейзмана.
М. М. Пришвин. Дневники (1914).
А потом, когда начнется голубой день, такая радость охватит всех, какая не известна ни одному защитнику света.
§ 57. Частица не с прилагательными
 8. Раздельное написание частицы не с прилагательным, 
 имеющим при себе пояснительные слова, встречается:
 2) при наличии в качестве пояснительных слов далеко, вовсе, 
 отнюдь или отрицательных местоимений и наречий 
 (начинающихся с ни): далеко не простое решение; вовсе не 
 бесплодные поиски; отнюдь не новый сюжет; никому не 
 известный адрес; ни в чём не повинные люди; нисколько не 
 понятное выражение; ничуть не вредный напиток; никому не 
 ведомыми путями (ср.: неведомыми мне путями). 

 

